# Rule of preposition

Tags: prepositions

Someone asked me this question which I could not able to answer:

> then my question is , " I gave a book to him"--- here why we don't use
>   a preposition before a book? Or " he killed a snake with a stick" ..
>   Why here is also no preposition before a snake?

I told him that this is the rule of sentence construction so we have to follow them. It also occurred to me that may be the preposition is just sandwiched between two nouns and there are no other parts of speech in between. But in this case why is there a preposition "with" after "snake".

There was another question raised by him:

```
"he is at home" 
"I gave him books"

Why is there preposition "at" before "home" but not a preposition between "him" and "books"?
```

Please help me help him :)

Thanks

Comment: Have you explained the idea of a direct object? All the examples without prepositions are direct objects, and that is not a coincidence. _At home_ is not a direct object.

Comment: The basic function of prepositions is to clarify case relations among substantives. Since the relation of subject to direct object is the most fundamental of such relations, no preposition is needed or wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It's because prepositions get deleted after verbs, sometimes.  The pattern is clearer with the verb "present": "He presented a flower to her."/"He presented her with a flower."  A basic "present with a flower to her" can have the prepositional phrases in either order, and the preposition that winds up next to the verb is lost.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you how to predict whether a preposition will be lost after a verb.  Also, I don't know why "give", unlike "present", allows a prepositionless object after the indirect object.

Comment: The "missing" prepositions in the question would all appear before a _direct object_. Are you saying that direct objects usually are preceded by prepositions, but they get "deleted"?

Comment: I think _present_ is the exception here, not _give_. Are you sure that the flower is the direct object in _he presented her with a flower_?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, essentially (I believe that was also proposed by Charles Fillmore in "A proposal concerning English prepositions").  I proposed it for "present" and similar verbs in a 1966 paper at the Chicago Linguistic Society.  I don't believe I said that "flower" is the direct object in *presented her with a flower*, and it is pretty obvious that it is not.

Comment: The question "why _give_ allows a prepositionless object" seems to imply that it's _give_ that behaves strangely, but I think in general, direct objects don't take a preposition. So no prepositions disappeared (or are "missing" in the OP's examples).

Comment: @oerkelens, of course direct objects don't take a preposition.  If they did, they wouldn't be direct objects.  You can't prove anything by arguing in a circle.  And I didn't say anything about *give* being exceptional.

Comment: The question, really, is whether the prepositions are just stickers that can be discarded once they've been recognized -- with default preposition deletion for nouns bearing grammatical relations (Su, DO, IO) -- or whether they're actually significant and define phrases. Obviously they do quite a bit of both, and often enough the views predict the same phenomena. I have always considered prepositions as syntactic auxiliaries first, and semantic items second. In fact, I've found figuring out the semantics of prepositions is just as fraught as figuring out the phonosemantics of open class words.

Comment: The proposal of my 1967 MA thesis, *The English preposition "with"*, was to identify the *with* that occurs in indirect object constructions, reduced relative *have* clauses, and absolute constructions (*With his work done, John ...*) as being associated with subjects of certain sentences which express movement or association.  (For *give*, the direct object moves to or becomes associated with the indirect object.)

Comment: Sounds cool. Was that at UChi? I got my MA the same year, as it happens, at UWash; this was before I learned syntax.

Comment: No, Ohio State.  The thesis was in OSU Working Papers in Linguistics #1, I think.

Comment: I found it (a blurry version): http://linguistics.osu.edu/sites/linguistics.osu.edu/files/osu_wpl_01_sm.pdf

Comment: Wow. Along with Fillmore's "The Grammar of Hitting and Breaking". Those were the days.